# Is there any option to create multiple dict from array elements in python

Tags: python

I want to create multiple `dict` at one go :

I have a list: `a=[a,b,c,d]`
Now want to create multiple `dict` from the above list as `a={}`,`b={}`,`c={}`,`d={}`

Comment: Why do u need such thing?

Comment: What are `a,b,c,d`? Are they supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 1):

using `dict`

```
a=["a","b","c","d"] 
print( dict((i,{}) for i in a) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': {}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}, 'd': {}}
```